# Improved first person controller ursina engine

Tags: controller, gravity, ursina

So im trying to create a game of parkour in ursina engine, and i want to know if there is a way to improve the gravity and the jump of the firstpersoncontroller, because sometimes, the player go in the ground. The parkour object has collider set as "mesh". I already had this issue when i tried to create "minecraft in python" of ClearCode[image][image: the green thing is at the pos of the first person controller]

Is it possible to "improve" the first person controller gravity?

Comment: Please add code excerpts where you instantiate the relevant entities, configure collisions, etc. It's possible that you're setting the collisions incorrectly or on the wrong objects, but it's difficult to diagnose such without explicit code.  You might also benefit from comparing your code to a tutorial like this one: https://www.ursinaengine.org/platformer_tutorial.html

Comment: The problem is i dont properly configure collisions because its the ursina engine "FirstPersonController"